# Removing collected charges in a IC CMOS circuit exposed under a 30keV electron beam source

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, microscopy

I would like to know if there is any mechanism (for example UV light exposition) to remove charges collected in an IC CMOS circuit that was exposed under a 30keV electron beam source. Presumably, those charges were collected in the MOS oxides.

The CMOS circuit is a Sensor Image and some pixels appear as illuminated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many particle physics detectors (e.g. CERN) are made to be annealed at moderate temperatures (100-200C or so as I recall). May not apply to commercial sensors, so a test might be needed to see if (or how many cycles) it would survive.